# How can I replace multiples value using regex_repalce in sql?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have column in which different values are there like

| refer_nO |
| --- |
| Post-factos022110 |
| P0st-fact04433 |
| Postfact0s304004 |
| Postfact202934 |

Now I want to keep the numbers and replace all non-numbers values with blank, Wanting something like this

| refer_nO |
| --- |
| 022110 |
| 04433 |
| 304004 |
| 202934 |

To replace one single value I can use

`select regex_replace(column1,"Post-factos"," ") from table`

How can I replace mutiples values ?

Answer (score 0):

Use regex `[^0-9]+` to remove all non-numeric characters:

```sql
select regexp_replace(column1,'[^0-9]+','') from table
```